# Python Quant Lib - Bond Pricing ex coupon period

Tags: programming, fixed-income, quantlib, pricing

were wondering If anyone knows how to use rate bonds on Python Quantlib, that have
an ex-coupon period.

For example the link below shows the construction of such a bond in the c++ quantlib
using
FixedRateBond bond(settlementDays, 100.0,
schedule,
std::vector(1, coupon),
dc, Unadjusted, 100.0,
issueDate, calendar, ***exCouponPeriod***, calendar);

How to do this in python???